# Explain this formula of geometric series/math magic

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recreational-mathematics

This is a magic trick that has a formula which I don't understand. 5 cards are used 3 black 2 red, so N = 5 (total cards) k=2 (red cards) and N-k=3 (black cards) and the magician always bets that the card drawn will be red for any shuffled combination of BBBRR cards. He multiplies his initial bet by y=3/2 for a loss and x=1/2 for a win. And he always bets 16$. The formula is [image: equation] which gives 5/16 for the given values of x and y. I think this has something to do with a geometric series but am not sure, does anyone know how to explain this formula or derive it?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Does he always bet $16 \$$ or does he multiply it? And what does the formula represent? What is it calculating? And when does the "trick" stop?

Comment: It's a roulette game, so the spectator shuffles the five cards and tells the magician what color he will bet on, e.g. red. The magician always bets $16 initially. So for a pack in the combination RBBBR it would look like this: https://imgur.com/a/9U0CW the formula gives the result 5/16 for the given xy values which is the expected value of the initial bet. So 16 * 5/16 = 5. It calculates expected value but I'm not sure how to derive it. Given that x + y =2 it works for any x

Comment: So the scenario is that the cards are shuffled and then the magician bets on which color card will come up (always choosing red) as each of the 5 cards are drawn one by one. Is this correct? And the question is: Given the magician's strategy, how is the formula for the expected return derived. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not being very clear in my first post, but that is how it goes.